# adding 2 strings from 2 foreach statements into a list

Tags: c#

I am trying to use 2 regex patterns to extract specific data from this pdf

```
public static void ReadPDF()
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"\\cytgit\Applications\C#\EZDock\CEVA.pdf"))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
            string pattern2 = @"^\W*([\w-]+.*\n{1})Route Name:";
            Regex r2 = new Regex(pattern2, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            foreach (Match m in r2.Matches(text))
            {
                Debug.Print((m.Value.Substring(0, 13)));
            }

            string pattern = @"(?<=.*Initial Arrival.*(\n)).*?(?=(\r?\n)|$)";
            Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (Match m in r.Matches(text))
            {

                List<string> stringList = m.Value.Split(' ').ToList();

                Routes.Add(new Routes { CarrierArrival = DateTime.Parse(stringList[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), CarrierDeparture = DateTime.Parse(stringList[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), PlantDestination = stringList[2], DockCode = stringList[3], InitialDest = stringList[4], InitialArrival = stringList[5], FinalLocation = stringList[6], Transit = stringList[7], PickupFreq = stringList[8], DeliveryFreq = stringList[9]});

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it prints the right data on the first `foreach` and the second `foreach` works great as well. My goal here is to put what is being printed in the first `foreach` into the same list as what is added in the second `foreach` `stringList` that way I can add `m.Value.Substring(0, 13)` into `stringList` to be able to add it to the new `Route`

Answer (score 1):

Create the list before the first `foreach`?:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
foreach (Match m in r2.Matches(text))
{
    stringList.Add(m.Value.Substring(0, 13));
}

string pattern = @"(?<=.*Initial Arrival.*(\n)).*?(?=(\r?\n)|$)";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(text))
{
    stringList.AddRange(m.Value.Split(' '));
    Routes.Add(...);

}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I add the first pattern in that becomes stringList[0-10] and 2nd pattern is at the end when there is nothing left from first pattern.

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3: Maybe you should consider clarifying your requirements a bit? What is your question?

Comment: It's going into a datagrid right now, when I am only using the 2nd pattern it goes into the datagrid correctly I'm just trying to add a new column that extracts something else with a different pattern and fill that column

Comment: idk how else to explain it? I've narrorwed it down to the last detail. Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one page of the pdf has multiple routes (name and details). The problem I see is matching the names with the corresponding information.

Foreach page I would try to split those route sections to get a list of sections. With an additional foreach loop extract the single name of the route with `pattern2` and the details with `pattern`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
    string routeSections[] = SplitPageInRouteSections(text);
    foreach(var routeSection in routeSections)
    {
        string routeName = Regex.Match(routeSection, pattern2).ToString()
        string[] details = Regex.Match(routeSection, pattern).ToString().Split(' ');
        Routes.Add(new Routes{ RouteName = routeName, CarrierArrival = details[0], ...})
    }
}
```